# Formatting "Wed Oct 12 12:42:08 IST 2016" using "dojo/date/locale" dojo Locale wiget

Tags: date, dojo

From backend I am receiving Date in this format "Wed Oct 12 12:42:08 IST 2016".

I need to format in this format -- "2016-10-12 12:42:08"

Iam using this method

```
 var somevar = new Date("Wed Oct 12 12:42:08 IST 2016");
 locale.format(somevar ,{selector :"date", datePattern:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} );
```

Please can anyone Help

Answer (score 1):

The reason behind why your date string is not working because it's format, somehow you need to use "Wed Oct 12 12:42:08 2016" instead of "Wed Oct 12 12:42:08 IST 2016" while creating your date for conversion. To achieve this, few options given below...

1. Try dojo/date/locale::parse() to parse date string coming from database then convert it to desired datetime format [link](https://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/date/locale/parse.html)dojo/date/locale::parse()

OR

2. If you want to use `var somevar = new Date("Wed Oct 12 12:42:08 IST 2016");` then in this case strip out 'IST' from this string as it is causing failure to parse this date format into javascript. Then you need to do something like this...

```js
var date_string = "Wed Oct 12 12:42:08 IST 2016";
var new_date_string = date_string.replace(/IST|CST|PMT/gi, "");
var somevar = new Date(new_date_string);
console.log(somevar);
//locale.format(somevar ,{selector :"date", datePattern:"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"} );
```

Comment: Thanks himesh for your answer.. As we were not allowed to hardcode replacing IST/ etc.. we requested back-end to send date in NUMBER format and then I parsed it..it  is working fine now.. :)